# namespaces - to 'use' or not to 'use'?

Tags: php, namespaces

I've been looking at a lot of frameworks lately, specifically Slim. Now, I don't plan on using it, but had a question anyway.  In Slim, it makes use of namespaces. However, it doesn't actually 'use' any of them.  You'll see `namespace Slim;` and then in the main index file it requires that class and then does stuff with it. Why use namespaces if not to `use` them?

What is the function/behavior of `use`ing namespaces as opposed to just putting `namespace xyz` before you start writing code?

Comment: It's the difference between writing code "in" a namespace and "use"ing a namespace that had code written in it. It's not very nice to [have to] write code "in" someone *else's* namespace - please refer to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) for initial questions.

Comment: Namespaces are just a great way to organize modules and libraries.  They can reduce name collisions and enhance program readability.  For whatever it's worth, I prefer Java and Ada "packages" more than C++ or C# "namespaces".  And I hasten to add: all four are significantly "different", although all four address the same general problem in a similar way.

Comment: Well, you can `use` more than one namespace, for a kick-off and have PHP work out where what class is to be found, unless there are several, in which case you can use `use namespace Group\Foo as GF` and create `new GF\Class_With_Name_Conflict`

Comment: @pst: I think you're right.  I assumed the question was "why namespaces?".  But I think the OP is confused between "use SOME_NAMESPACE" (my code is a client of that package), and "SOME_NAMESPACE" (my code is actually part of that package).  :)

Answer (score 3):

Just imagine namespaces as boxes.

If you're declaring :

```
namespace myBox;
```

The following code will be put inside that box.

```
class Test
{

   public function hello() {
      echo "Hello, world!\n";
   }

}
```

If you want to use that class in another piece of your application, you will do something like :

```
$test = new myBox\Test();
```

This is equivalent to :

```
use myBox\Test;

$test = new Test();
```

Namespaces just help you to design your app and organize things. In a very big app, with a framework which use a lot of technologies, namespaces avoid that two class has the same name for example.

Comment: Your equivalent isn't correct. It should be `use myBox\Test` to instantiate `new Test()`